# Name of interface used to write this message

Tags: php

I'm currently creating a CMS and I'd like to include a interface like the one I'm using right now to write this message. Something so you can change colors and font and size of the text without having to code. But I don't know how this thing is called. Can someone tell me and maybe also where to find documentation about how to implement it? I'd like to do that in PHP.

Thx :D

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: @Kittsil I just wanna know how such a thing is called so I can look for documentation on my own later on. Like when you press the enter key, the cursor will go to the next line and the "hidden code" behind it would be "</br>"

Answer (score 1):

The generic term I imagine you're looking for is a "WYSIWYG" ("what you see is what you get") editor. You'll need javascript to achieve it though. There are many out there though. A quick search should show you several.

- https://www.tinymce.com
- http://ckeditor.com
- http://nicedit.com
- http://phphtmledit.com
- http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_wysiwyg.htm

Comment: Thx! It's exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

What You See Is What You Get. or a "wysiwyg editor". Some common ones are http://ckeditor.com/ or https://www.tinymce.com/

You will have to implement a form and a way for the server to process that form data obviously. usually they simply hook into a textfield element.

Comment: Thx! It's exactly what I'm looking for!